# What's the best way to initialize a dict of dicts in Python?

Tags: python, autovivification

A lot of times in Perl, I'll do something like this:

```
$myhash{foo}{bar}{baz} = 1
```

How would I translate this to Python? So far I have:

```
if not 'foo' in myhash:
    myhash['foo'] = {}
if not 'bar' in myhash['foo']:
    myhash['foo']['bar'] = {}
myhash['foo']['bar']['baz'] = 1
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: ahem, indeed the other was asked 5 days before and these both are 4 years old ...

Answer (score 112, accepted):

```
class AutoVivification(dict):
    """Implementation of perl's autovivification feature."""
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        try:
            return dict.__getitem__(self, item)
        except KeyError:
            value = self[item] = type(self)()
            return value
```

Testing:

```
a = AutoVivification()

a[1][2][3] = 4
a[1][3][3] = 5
a[1][2]['test'] = 6

print a
```

Output:

```
{1: {2: {'test': 6, 3: 4}, 3: {3: 5}}}
```

Comment: Is it possible to extend it so it supports the following behavior: a[1][2][3] += some_value. So if the key did not exist in advance, then the a[1][2][3] would be initialized with the default value of the type(some_value)?

Comment: This function has the side effect that any attempts to get a non-existent key also creates the key. Typically you would only want to auto create a key if you were at the same time setting a key or subkey.

Comment: Is there also a way to make the assignment variable? So that given `var = [1,2,3]`, I could do like `a[var] = 1`, which would expand to `a[1][2][3] = 1`?

Comment: `var = [1,2]` would then allow `a[var] = 1` to be `a[1][2] = 1`

Comment: @Dualinity that already works if you use normal dicts and tuples: `d = {}; k = (1, 2, 3); d[k] = 1` then you can use `d[1,2,3]`. If you want to use `d[1][2][3]` (why?) you'd have to modify the recipe above, ask another question. remember tat flat is better than nested.

Comment: Because I want to have a structure with

Comment: Another solution would be...

`from collections import defaultdict`
followed by `AutoVivification = lambda: defaultdict(AutoVivification)`

This one seems more simple.  Subclassing dict though has the side effect of the dictionary being easier to read when printed though.

Source:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autovivification#Python

Comment: @AntonDaneyko to auto initialize a[1][2][3] += some_value  you can overwrite the method `def __iadd__(self, some_value):
        return some_value`

Answer (score 131):

If the amount of nesting you need is fixed, `collections.defaultdict` is wonderful.

e.g. nesting two deep:

```
myhash = collections.defaultdict(dict)
myhash[1][2] = 3
myhash[1][3] = 13
myhash[2][4] = 9
```

If you want to go another level of nesting, you'll need to do something like:

```
myhash = collections.defaultdict(lambda : collections.defaultdict(dict))
myhash[1][2][3] = 4
myhash[1][3][3] = 5
myhash[1][2]['test'] = 6
```

edit: MizardX points out that we can get full genericity with a simple function:

```
import collections
def makehash():
    return collections.defaultdict(makehash)
```

Now we can do:

```
myhash = makehash()
myhash[1][2] = 4
myhash[1][3] = 8
myhash[2][5][8] = 17
# etc
```

Comment: or def makehash(): return collections.defaultdict(makehash); myhash = makehash()

Comment: I've got no problems with "traditional" recursive functions, but there's something about that that I find unintuitive.  Odd.  Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for this.  That lambda: defaultdict() is what I needed.

Comment: Unfortunately that recursive makehash approach does not handle the following a = makehash(); a['foo'] += 1; as I understand it's because the default_factory is not specified here. Do you know how to overcome this issue?

Comment: This just saved my bacon on a data conversion project that was overdue before I started it.  I needed to do some time coalescing of log messages based on sec,msec tags; I really wanted to use hash-hash-list. tagtable = collections.defaultdict(lambda : collections.defaultdict(list)) really hit the spot.

Comment: makehash() is awesome. But is there a pythonic way to accomplish the same thing with a default value as well? Difficult, because the default value *is* a defaultdict()?

Comment: very handy it is when initializing, but it seems there's no easy way to work with this dict since there's lambda function involved, e.g. `print myhash` will get a bunch of `<function <lambda> at ...>` sort of thing.

Comment: @timfeirg you can use json lib to overcome this: `import json; print json.dumps(myhash)`.

Answer (score 16):

Is there a reason it needs to be a dict of dicts?  If there's no compelling reason for that particular structure, you could simply index the dict with a tuple:

```
mydict = {('foo', 'bar', 'baz'):1} # Initializes dict with a key/value pair
mydict[('foo', 'bar', 'baz')]      # Returns 1

mydict[('foo', 'unbar')] = 2       # Sets a value for a new key
```

The parentheses are required if you initialize the dict with a tuple key, but you can omit them when setting/getting values using []:

```
mydict = {}                        # Initialized the dict
mydict['foo', 'bar', 'baz'] = 1    # Sets a value
mydict['foo', 'bar', 'baz']        # Returns 1
```

Comment: Can you be clear on when you can omit the parentheses? Is it because the comma is the tuple operator, and the parentheses only needed if we have ambiguous grouping?

Comment: This may actually be faster than nested dictionaries because there is one lookup instead of three.

Comment: Yes for initializing well defined structures which are then written to json? A very common case/practice...

Answer (score 2):

I guess the literal translation would be:

```
 mydict = {'foo' : { 'bar' : { 'baz':1}}}
```

Calling:

```
 >>> mydict['foo']['bar']['baz']
```

gives you 1.

That looks a little gross to me, though.

(I'm no perl guy, though, so I'm guessing at what your perl does)

Comment: That only works at initialization time, though, right?

Comment: @Dana, as opposed to adding new values to mydict during runtime.