# Multiple levels of 'collection.defaultdict' in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

Thanks to some great folks on SO, I discovered the possibilities offered by `collections.defaultdict`, notably in readability and speed. I have put them to use with success.

Now I would like to implement three levels of dictionaries, the two top ones being `defaultdict` and the lowest one being `int`. I don't find the appropriate way to do this. Here is my attempt:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(defaultdict)
a = [("key1", {"a1":22, "a2":33}),
     ("key2", {"a1":32, "a2":55}),
     ("key3", {"a1":43, "a2":44})]
for i in a:
    d[i[0]] = i[1]
```

Now this works, but the following, which is the desired behavior, doesn't:

```
d["key4"]["a1"] + 1
```

I suspect that I should have declared somewhere that the second level `defaultdict` is of type `int`, but I didn't find where or how to do so.

The reason I am using `defaultdict` in the first place is to avoid having to initialize the dictionary for each new key.

Any more elegant suggestion?

Thanks pythoneers!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [defaultdict of defaultdict?](/q/5029934/90527)

Comment: As you can see, my question was answered in 2010.

Comment: Those comments are posted automatically when marking a question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 390, accepted):

Use:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
```

This will create a new `defaultdict(int)` whenever a new key is accessed in `d`.

Comment: Only problem is it won't pickle, meaning `multiprocessing` is unhappy about sending these back and forth.

Comment: @Noah: It will pickle if you use a named module-level function instead of a lambda.

Comment: @interjay can you elaborate on this please?

Comment: @ScienceFriction Anything specific that you need help with? When `d[new_key]` is accessed, it will call the lambda which will create a new `defaultdict(int)`. And when `d[existing_key][new_key2]` is accessed, a new `int` will be created.

Comment: This is awesome. It seems I renew my marital vows to Python daily.

Comment: Looking for more details about using this method with `multiprocessing` and what a named module-level function is? This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16439301/cant-pickle-defaultdict) follows up.

Comment: I get a `NameError: global name 'defaultdict' is not defined` error calling  `d["key4"]["a1"] +=1` . What's going on? I've imported `defaultdict` from `collections` so it should be in my namespace.

Comment: ultimate answer!... Thanks. worked in both 3.5 and 2.7.

Comment: How can this be generalized to work with an arbitrary number of levels? edit: i'm now seeing a newer answer near the bottom which generalizes by subclassing defaultdict and that will work nicely for me. out of curiosity, can THIS answer (ie the lambda approach) be similarly generalized?

Comment: @ibonyun You can add an additional level in the same manner, e.g. `d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int)))`

Answer (score 36):

Another way to make a pickleable, nested defaultdict is to use a partial object instead of a lambda:

```
from functools import partial
...
d = defaultdict(partial(defaultdict, int))
```

This will work because the defaultdict class is globally accessible at the module level:

> "You can't pickle a partial object unless the function [or in this
>   case, class] it wraps is globally accessible ... under its __name__
>   (within its __module__)"
>   -- [Pickling wrapped partial functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14550577/pickling-wrapped-partial-functions#comment20302657_14550773)

Answer (score 14):

Look at nosklo's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/651879) for a more general solution.

```
class AutoVivification(dict):
    """Implementation of perl's autovivification feature."""
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        try:
            return dict.__getitem__(self, item)
        except KeyError:
            value = self[item] = type(self)()
            return value
```

Testing:

```
a = AutoVivification()

a[1][2][3] = 4
a[1][3][3] = 5
a[1][2]['test'] = 6

print a
```

Output:

```
{1: {2: {'test': 6, 3: 4}, 3: {3: 5}}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the link @miles82 (and the edit, @voyager). How pythonesque and safe is this approach?

Comment: Unfortunately this solution doesn't preserve the handiest part of defaultdict, which is the power to write something like D['key']+=1 without worrying about the existence of the key. That's the main feature I use defaultdict for... but I can imagine dynamically deepening dictionaries are pretty handy too.

Comment: @rschwieb you can add the power to write += 1 by adding __add__ method.

Answer (score 7):

As per @rschwieb's request for `D['key'] += 1`, we can expand on [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2600847/117714) by overriding addition by defining `__add__` method, to make this behave more like a `collections.Counter()`

First `__missing__` will be called to create a new empty value, which will be passed into `__add__`.  We test the value, counting on empty values to be `False`.

See [emulating numeric types](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types) for more information on overriding.

```
from numbers import Number


class autovivify(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        value = self[key] = type(self)()
        return value

    def __add__(self, x):
        """ override addition for numeric types when self is empty """
        if not self and isinstance(x, Number):
            return x
        raise ValueError

    def __sub__(self, x):
        if not self and isinstance(x, Number):
            return -1 * x
        raise ValueError
```

Examples:

```
>>> import autovivify
>>> a = autovivify.autovivify()
>>> a
{}
>>> a[2]
{}
>>> a
{2: {}}
>>> a[4] += 1
>>> a[5][3][2] -= 1
>>> a
{2: {}, 4: 1, 5: {3: {2: -1}}}
```

Rather than checking argument is a Number (very non-python, amirite!) we could just provide a default 0 value and then attempt the operation:

```
class av2(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        value = self[key] = type(self)()
        return value

    def __add__(self, x):
        """ override addition when self is empty """
        if not self:
            return 0 + x
        raise ValueError

    def __sub__(self, x):
        """ override subtraction when self is empty """
        if not self:
            return 0 - x
        raise ValueError
```

Comment: should these raise NotImplemented rather than ValueError?

Answer (score 6):

Late to the party, but for arbitrary depth I just found myself doing something like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

class DeepDict(defaultdict):
    def __call__(self):
        return DeepDict(self.default_factory)
```

The trick here is basically to make the `DeepDict` instance itself a valid factory for constructing missing values. Now we can do things like

```
dd = DeepDict(DeepDict(list))
dd[1][2].extend([3,4])
sum(dd[1][2])  # 7

ddd = DeepDict(DeepDict(DeepDict(list)))
ddd[1][2][3].extend([4,5])
sum(ddd[1][2][3])  # 9
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def _sub_getitem(self, k):
    try:
        # sub.__class__.__bases__[0]
        real_val = self.__class__.mro()[-2].__getitem__(self, k)
        val = '' if real_val is None else real_val
    except Exception:
        val = ''
        real_val = None
    # isinstance(Avoid,dict)也是true，会一直递归死
    if type(val) in (dict, list, str, tuple):
        val = type('Avoid', (type(val),), {'__getitem__': _sub_getitem, 'pop': _sub_pop})(val)
        # 重新赋值当前字典键为返回值，当对其赋值时可回溯
        if all([real_val is not None, isinstance(self, (dict, list)), type(k) is not slice]):
            self[k] = val
    return val


def _sub_pop(self, k=-1):
    try:
        val = self.__class__.mro()[-2].pop(self, k)
        val = '' if val is None else val
    except Exception:
        val = ''
    if type(val) in (dict, list, str, tuple):
        val = type('Avoid', (type(val),), {'__getitem__': _sub_getitem, 'pop': _sub_pop})(val)
    return val


class DefaultDict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, k):
        return _sub_getitem(self, k)

    def pop(self, k):
        return _sub_pop(self, k)

In[8]: d=DefaultDict()
In[9]: d['a']['b']['c']['d']
Out[9]: ''
In[10]: d['a']="ggggggg"
In[11]: d['a']
Out[11]: 'ggggggg'
In[12]: d['a']['pp']
Out[12]: ''
```

No errors again. 
No matter how many levels  nested.
pop  no error also

dd=DefaultDict({"1":333333})