# Can Python dictionaries to be as handy as PHP array?

Tags: php, python

Recently, I'm working on a Python-based project and facing a issue with dictionaries. In PHP I can easily create a multiple dimension array by the following instruction:

```
$user = "Tom";
$type = "New";
$userlist[$user]['count'] += 1;
$userlist[$user][$type] += 1;
```

PHP will create a new element within an array if it doesn't exist, which is very convenient for coding. Can Python dictionaries provide the same and handy function as PHP?

Comment: Why wouldn't you use the actual OOP features of Python instead? This question just sounds a bit trollish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python does not magically instantiate dictionaries as PHP does; however, with a bit of forethought, you can make it do what you want.

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

users = defaultdict(Counter)

users['Tom']['Count'] += 1
users['Tom']['New'] += 1
```

(also, calling a variable "somethinglist" when it's not a list is probably a bad idea, and `type` is a Python keyword, so don't use it as a variable name either!)

Comment: ImportError: cannot import name Counter. Any idea?

Comment: @Cheng-Lin Yang: are you using a version of Python prior to 2.7? If so, I recommend http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576611/ as a replacement.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Python's defaultdict (as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2600813/183791) suggests):

```
from collections import defaultdict
user = "Tom"
type = "New"
userlist = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
userlist[user]['count'] += 1
userlist[user][type] += 1
```