# Are partial functions "officially" picklable?

Tags: python, pickle, functools

I need to create a bunch of [`partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#partial-objects) functions that can be pickled. Empirically testing this, it seems to work fine:

```py
import pickle
import functools

pickle.dumps(functools.partial(int, base=2))
# b'\x80\x03cfunctools\npartial\nq\x00cbuiltins\nint\nq\x01\x85q\x02Rq\x03(h\x01)}q\x04X\x04\x00\x00\x00baseq\x05K\x02sNtq\x06b.'
```

However, this is not stated explicitly in the documentation, and the given "roughly equivalent" function of [`functools.partial()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functools.html#functools.partial) is not picklable.

Can I assume that `partial` objects are picklable in any circumstances (no edge cases, independently of the C / Python implementation)?

Comment: Did you look at the [actual implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/functools.py#L234)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: That implementation gets replaced by the `from _functools import partial` below.

Comment: @user2357112 possibly, yes, but the point is still that the roughly equivalent implementation isn't the actual implementation.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I was mainly worried about differences between C and Python implementations.  Should I consider the "picklability" an implementation detail? It seems not according, partial objects not being picklable has been considered as a bug: https://bugs.python.org/issue1398 and https://bugs.python.org/issue27137 Still, can't find changelog about this.

Comment: Could you [edit] to reflect that? The roughly equivalent version is irrelevant in that case.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I removed the irrelevant code snippet.

Comment: Have you read the pickle docs? There's a whole section on how to create your own pickleable classes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14550577/pickling-wrapped-partial-functions Did you read the comments to the answer here?

Comment: If it helps, as far as I can tell, pickle doesn't care much about cross-implementation compatibility. So it seems safe to assume that `partial` objects can be always be pickled, but you might run into problems if you pickle one with CPython and try to unpickle it with PyPy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code snippet in the documentation simulating the `partial()` function is not picklable as it uses nested function. However, the official `functools.partial()` is implemented using a `class` which is pickable: [`cpython/functools.py#L234`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/164bee296ab1f87cc05566b39ee8fb9fb64b3e5a/Lib/functools.py#L234)

The official Python issue tracker contains several references for `partial` objects not beeing picklable, and this has been considered as a bug:

- [Can't pickle partial functions](https://bugs.python.org/issue1398)
- [Python implementation of `functools.partial` is not a class](https://bugs.python.org/issue27137)

Also, there are unit tests to check picklability of `partial` objects: [`cpython/test_functools.py#L244`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/142566c028720934325f0b7fe28680afd046e00f/Lib/test/test_functools.py#L244)

The [changelog](https://docs.python.org/3.6/whatsnew/changelog.html#id122) for Python 3.6 contains reference to the picklability of `functools.partial` objects:

> [bpo-27137](https://bugs.python.org/issue27137): the pure Python fallback implementation of `functools.partial` now matches the behaviour of its accelerated C counterpart for subclassing, pickling and text representation purposes.

For these reasons, I think one can safely assume that `partial` picklability is not an implementation detail and can be relied upon.

Comment: As I mentioned in the comments on the question, the thing in `functools.py` is not the actual implementation. It's an alternate implementation that gets replaced immediately.