# Cannot use ProcessPoolExecutor if in a decorator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle, concurrent.futures

I have this minimal example:

```
from functools import wraps
from concurrent import futures
import random

def decorator(func):
    num_process = 4

    def impl(*args, **kwargs):
        with futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
            fs = []
            for i in range(num_process):
                fut = executor.submit(func, *args, **kwargs)
                fs.append(fut)
            result = []
            for f in futures.as_completed(fs):
                result.append(f.result())
        return result
    return impl

@decorator
def get_random_int():
    return random.randint(0, 100)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    result = get_random_int()
    print(result)
```

If we try to run this function I think we will have the following error:

```
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function get_random_int at 0x7f06cee666a8>: it's not the same object as __main__.get_random_int
```

I think the main issue here is that the "wraps" decorator itself alters the `func` object and thus make it impossible to pickle. I found this rather strange. I am just wondering if there is any way to get around this behavior? I would want to use `wraps` if possible. Thanks!

Comment: Agree. I've seen a similar issue. It complains about the pickling. Wondering if anyone has a way to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `run_in_executor` is calling `functools.partial` on the decorated function see: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio-pass-keywords  <s>The picklability of partial objects is spotty (see: [Are partial functions "officially" picklable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58361373/are-partial-functions-officially-picklable)) but</s> See this comment over here [Pickling wrapped partial functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14550577/pickling-wrapped-partial-functions#comment20302657_14550773) partial functions are only pickleable when the function being pickled is in the global name sapce.  We know `run_in_executor` with a `ProcessPoolExecutor` will work for non wrapped functions since that pattern is documented in asyncio.  To get around this I decorate a dummy function and pass the function I want to be executed in multiple processes as an argument to the decorator

```
from functools import wraps
from concurrent import futures
import random

def decorator(multiprocess_func):
    def _decorate(func):
        num_process = 4

        def impl(*args, **kwargs):
            with futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
                fs = []
                for i in range(num_process):
                    fut = executor.submit(multiprocess_func, *args, **kwargs)
                    fs.append(fut)
                result = []
                for f in futures.as_completed(fs):
                    result.append(f.result())
            return result
        return impl
    return _decorate

def _get_random_int():
    return random.randint(0, 100)

@decorator(_get_random_int)
def get_random_int():
    return _get_random_int()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    result = get_random_int()
    print(result)
```

I ultimately decided that not using a decorator was cleaner

```
from concurrent import futures
import random

def decorator(multiprocess_func):
    num_process = 4

    def impl(*args, **kwargs):
        with futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=num_process) as executor:
            fs = []
            for i in range(num_process):
                fut = executor.submit(multiprocess_func, *args, **kwargs)
                fs.append(fut)
            result = []
            for f in futures.as_completed(fs):
                result.append(f.result())
        return result
    return impl

def _get_random_int():
    return random.randint(0, 100)

get_random_int = decorator(_get_random_int)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    result = get_random_int()
    print(result)
```

Similar to the linked answer above about pickling wrapped partial functions.