# Pickling a dictionary that uses defaultdict

Tags: python, dictionary, pickle

I have this dictionary defined by:

```
def train(features):
    model = collections.defaultdict(lambda: 1)
    for f in features:
        model[f] += 1
    return model
```

Later along the way, I want to to use pickle and dump the dictionary into a text file:

```
f = open('dict.txt', 'wb')
pickle.dump(Nwords, f)
```

However the code doesn't work and I receive an error. Apparently `pickle` can't work with `lambda` and I'm better off defining the `model` using a module-level function. I have already read the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16439301/cant-pickle-defaultdict)

Unfortunately as I am not experienced with Python I am not exactly sure how to do this. I tried:

```
def dd():
    return defaultdict(int)

def train(features):
##    model = defaultdict(lambda: 1)
    model = defaultdict(dd)
    for f in features:
        model[f] += 1
    return model
```

I receive the error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'collections.defaultdict' and 'int'
```

Other than that, `return defaultdict(int)` would always assign a zero to the first occurrence of a key, whereas I want it to assign 1. Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, that answer there is correct for that question, but subtly wrong for yours. Although a top-level function instead of a lambda is great and indeed would make pickle a lot happier, the function should return the default value to be used, which for your case is *not* another `defaultdict` object.

Simply return the same value your `lambda` returns:

```
def dd():
    return 1
```

Every time you try to access a key in the `defaultdict` instance that doesn't yet exist, `dd` is called. The other post then returns *another* `defaultdict` instance, that one set to use `int` as a default, which matches the lambda shown in the other question.