# Loading a pkl file using dill

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, pickle, dill

I have a very complex dictionary and dumping, loading directly using dill works. This is in reference to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21239587/3231320). But there is a slight modification. I need to save this in some file and read that file for later use.

Here's a piece of my code:

`NWORDSa` is the dictionary that i saved into `'abc.pkl'`

```
pdict1 = dill.dumps(NWORDSa)
dill.dump_session('abc.pkl')
```

I do not know how to read it back to get the original `NWORDSa`. I tried:

```
c = dill.load_session('abc.pkl')
NWORDS_b= dill.loads(c)
```

and
(wanted to save it in a variable bbn)

```
with open('abc.pkl', 'rb') as f:
     pickle.dump(bbn, f)
```

But both do not work. Is there a better method?

Comment: use `.pt` for pickle file extension (or at least that's what pycharm highlights which makes me assume that is the common extension).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're dumping the session, not the dictionary itself. I don't know if saving / loading the session is even needed - that depends on your setup.

Try:

```
with open(outfile, 'wb') as out_strm: 
    dill.dump(datastruct, out_strm)
```

and:

```
with open(infile, 'rb') as in_strm:
    datastruct = dill.load(in_strm)
```

If you need to dump the session, use `dill.dump_session('session.pkl')` before and `dill.load_session('session.pkl')` after.

Comment: use `.pt` for pickle file extension (or at least that's what pycharm highlights which makes me assume that is the common extension).