# How to pickle a defaultdict which uses a lambda function?

Tags: python, lambda, pickle, defaultdict

How do I create pickle file of function (`defaultDict`)? The error I get is
can't `pickle function objects`

```
from collections import defaultdict
dtree = lambda: defaultdict(tree)

try:    import cPickle as pickle
except: import pickle

#Create defaultdict  object:
hapPkl = dtree()

#Create Pickle file
f  = open("hapP.pkl","wb")
pickle.dump(hapPkl,f)
f.close()
```

StackTrace:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-287-376cac3b4f0d> in <module>()
      1 f  = open("hapP.pkl","wb")
----> 2 pickle.dump(hapPkl,f)
      3 f.close()

/usr/lib64/python2.7/copy_reg.pyc in _reduce_ex(self, proto)
     68     else:
     69         if base is self.__class__:
---> 70             raise TypeError, "can't pickle %s objects" % base.__name__
     71         state = base(self)
     72     args = (self.__class__, base, state)

TypeError: can't pickle function objects
```

Comment: Where is `tree` coming from? You only define `dtree`.

Comment: In Python 3, pickling functions works if they're defined using a `def` statement, but not if they're defined with a `lambda` (even if the `lambda` is assigned to a variable). Try `def dtree(): return defaultdict(dtree)` maybe?

Comment: @Blckknght  using Python 2.

Comment: @user2357112,  Weird, does not throw an error

Comment: I hadn't checked when I wrote the comment above, but the behavior is the same in Python 2 (it just has less clear error messages).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple workaround would be to implement your tree data-structure differently, without `defaultdict`:

```
class DTree(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        value = self[key] = type(self)()
        return value

try:    import cPickle as pickle
except: import pickle

#Create dtree object:
hapPkl = DTree()

#Create Pickle file
with open("hapP.pkl", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(hapPkl, f)
```

Comment: what would be the benefits of this?

Comment: It's arguably a better way to do it. An important one is that it prints and pretty-prints (`pprint()`) like a normal dictionary. See [_What is the best way to implement nested dictionaries in Python?_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635483/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-nested-dictionaries-in-python/19829714#19829714)

Answer (score 5):

The `cPickle` error message is a bit misleading; the `pickle` version is better. It's not that you can't pickle functions; it's that they need to be available by their `__name__`. A lambda has `__name__` set to `'<lambda>'`, so it's not picklable. Define it with `def`:

```
def tree():
    return defaultdict(tree)
```

and it will be picklable. (You'll still need a matching definition of `tree` available when you unpickle it.)

Comment: Related info can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16439301/cant-pickle-defaultdict

Comment: @user, what do you mean by: matching definition?

Comment: @Merlin: If you try to unpickle this defaultdict in an environment with no definition of `tree`, it won't work.

Comment: @user2357112, what wont work.. the unpickling, or the nesting of defaultdicts.