# Can't pickle recursive nested defaultdict

Tags: python, inheritance, pickle, defaultdict

I have a recursive nested `defaultdict` class defined as

```
from collections import defaultdict

class NestedDict(defaultdict):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(self.__class__)
```

sitting in a `nested_dict.py` file.

When I try to pickle it, e.g.

```
import pickle
from nested_dict import NestedDict

d = NestedDict()
pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(d))
```

I get `TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`.

What's exactly happening here?

Comment: Changing the `super().__init__(self.__class__)` line to `super().__init__()` would make this class a `defaultdict` without a factory, which essentially works like the built-in `dict`. Not a good idea.

Comment: oh, sorry about that, nevermind then.

Comment: this may be the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16439301/cant-pickle-defaultdict

Comment: @goldy021 - it's not the same problem, pickle can't serialize lambdas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `defaultdict` class implements a [`object.__reduce__()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#object.__reduce__) where the second element of the returned tuple (the arguments for the constructor) is always going to be the factory object:

```
>>> d = NestedDict()
>>> d.__reduce__()
(<class '__main__.NestedDict'>, (<class '__main__.NestedDict'>,), None, None, <dict_itemiterator object at 0x110df59a8>)
```

That argument is then passed to the `NestedDict()` call to re-build the object. The exception is thrown because the `NestedDict` class doesn’t accept an argument.

You can override the `__reduce__` method in your subclass:

```
class NestedDict(defaultdict):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(self.__class__)
    def __reduce__(self):
        return (type(self), (), None, None, iter(self.items()))
```

The above produces the exact same elements `defaultdict.__reduce__()` returns, except that the second element is now an empty tuple.

You could also just accept and ignore a single argument:

```
class NestedDict(defaultdict):
    def __init__(self, _=None):  # accept a factory and ignore it
        super().__init__(self.__class__)
```

The `_` name is commonly used to mean *I am ignoring this value*.

An alternative implementation could just subclass `dict` and provide a custom [`__missing__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__missing__); this method is called for keys not in the dictionary:

```
class NestedDict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        nested = self[key] = type(self)()
        return nested
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{type(self).__name__}({super().__repr__()})'
```

This works exactly like your version, but doesn't need additional pickle support methods:

```
>>> d = NestedDict()
>>> d['foo']
NestedDict({})
>>> d['foo']['bar']
NestedDict({})
>>> d
NestedDict({'foo': NestedDict({'bar': NestedDict({})})})
>>> pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(d))
NestedDict({'foo': NestedDict({'bar': NestedDict({})})})
```