# Python defaultdict(lambda: None) without lambda

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have code using a `ProcessPoolExecutor` which can't pickle lambdas and functions. Some of the code that I want to execute in parallel uses a `defaultdict` with a default value of `None`.

How would you proceed? If at all possible, I would not like to touch the parallelizing code.

What I have:

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.some_dict = defaultdict(lambda: None)

    def generate(self):
        <some code>

def some_method_to_parallelize(x: SomeClass):
    <some code>

def some_method():
    max_workers = round(os.cpu_count() // 1.5)
    invocations_per_process = 100
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=max_workers) as executor:    
        data = [executor.submit(some_method_to_parallelize, SomeClass())] for _ in range(invocations_per_process)]
        data = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([r.result() for r in data]))
```

Comment: May be related [Can't pickle defaultdict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16439301/cant-pickle-defaultdict)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
collections.defaultdict(type(None))
```

That gets you a reference to `NoneType` for use as your `defaultdict`'s default factory. When constructed, it produces `None`, and unlike a `lambda`, appears to be picklable.

Comment: Exactly the standard way I've been looking for.