# Cannot load defaultdict of defaultdict object from pickle file

Tags: python, dictionary, pickle, n-gram, defaultdict

I am trying to store this defaultdict object using pickle:

```py
def dd():
    return defaultdict(int)
model = defaultdict(dd)
```

My first try was to use lambda, but according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16439301/cant-pickle-defaultdict), I have changed it to external function. Still, when I want to load my object using following code:

```py
import pickle
file = open("../model/trigram-model.pkl", "rb")
model = pickle.load(file)
```

It gives me the following error:

```
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'dd' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>
```

I have tried redefining `dd` function as well, but it then shows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 74
```

Comment: You have to import `dd` before trying to load the pickle file.

Comment: what is the difference between importing and defining?

Comment: If I define `dd` before calling `pickle.load(file)` it works fine for me.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to define dd before loading, and now that I defined it before, it works!