# autovivificating multiprocessing manager() dictionaries in python

Tags: python, dictionary, multiprocessing, autovivification

I'm using autovivification to store data in a multiprocessing setting. However, I can't figure out how to incorporate it in the multiprocessing manager function.

My autovivification code comes from [Multiple levels of 'collection.defaultdict' in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600790/multiple-levels-of-collection-defaultdict-in-python) and works fine when no multiprocessing occurs.

```
class vividict(dict):  
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        try:
            return dict.__getitem__(self, item)
        except KeyError:
            value = self[item] = type(self)()
            return value
```

My multiproc code is relative simpel:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    man = Manager()
    ngramDict = man.dict()
    print(ngramDict) # {}
    s_queue = Queue()

    aProces = Process(target=insert_ngram, args=(s_queue,ngramDict,))
    aProces.start()
    aProces.join()
    print(ngramDict) # {}
    write_to_file()
```

In insert_ngram the dictionary is read, written and updated:

```
def insert_ngram(sanitize_queue, ngramDict):
    ngramDict = Vividict() # obviously this overwrites the manager
    try:
        for w in iter(s_queue.get, None):
        if ngramDict[w[0]][w[1]][w[2]][w[3]][w[4]]:
            ngramDict[w[0]][w[1]][w[2]][w[3]][w[4]]+=int(w[5])
        else:
            ngramDict[w[0]][w[1]][w[2]][w[3]][w[4]]=int(w[5])
    print(ngramDict) # prints the expected ngramdict
    return
except KeyError as e:
    print("Key %s not found in %s" % (e, ngramDict))
except Exception as e:
    print("%s failed with: %s" % (current_process().name, e))
```

I've tried a series of what I thought were good solutions, but I can't get it to work, except for calling `write_to_file` in `insert_ngram` but that's not really a neat solution.

Is there a possibility to get Manager.dict() to autovivifacte?

--------- **UPDATE 6-12-2013** --------

Since the `Manager()` provdes a proxy, any mutations to a `manager.Dict()` within a subprocess aren't stored/kept track of. (see also: [How does multiprocessing.Manager() work in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436757/how-does-multiprocessing-manager-work-in-python))
This can be solved as folows:

```
def insert_ngram(sanitize_queue, ngramDict):
    localDict = Vividict()
    localDict.update(ngramDict)
    #do stuff
    ngramDict.update(ngramiDict)
```

I'm waiting for my machine to finish some tasks so I can see how this performs. It seems  like a performance-hit to copy Dicts up and down like this. (my Dicts run into the 200Mb+)

--------- **UPDATE 8-12-2013** --------
In my application, the dict.update() is only hit once, so even though the Dict is ~200Mb+, on the whole it's not a big performance impact...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The multiprocessing `Manager()` provdes a proxy to a dictionary or list. Any mutations to a `manager.Dict()` within a subprocess aren't stored/kept track of. One thus needs to copy the mutations to the proxy-variable that belongs to the Manager. 
(see also: [How does multiprocessing.Manager() work in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436757/how-does-multiprocessing-manager-work-in-python))

This can be solved as folows:

```
def insert_ngram(queue, managerDict):
    # create a local dictionary with vivification
    localDict = Vividict() 
    # copy the existing manager.dict to the local dict.
    localDict.update(managerDict) 
    #do stuff 
    # copy the local dictionary to the manager dict
    managerDict.update(localDict) 
    return
```

Although this seems like some serious overhead, in this case it's not too bad, as the manager dictionary only needs to update() before joining with the main process.