# Best way to check Python multi-level dictionary

Tags: python

Currently I am using the following method, assume dictionary

```
data[a][b][c]
```

I use:

```
if "a" in data and "b" in data["a"] and "c" in data["a"]["b"]:
  ...
```

Are there any better way?

Comment: Vote for leave "as is" :)

Answer (score 8):

You can wrap it in a try/except block

```
try:
    x = data[a][b][c]
    ...do stuff in your "if" clause
except KeyError:
    ...do stuff in your "else" clause
```

Answer (score 7):

I would typically use the pattern

```
foo = data.get("a",{}).get("b",{}).get("c",False)
if foo:
...
```

This requires that the nesting is always the same depth and that data["a"]["b"]["c"] is not "falsy".

Answer (score 3):

If you need to do this multi-level lookup very often, this helper method can be useful:

```py
def multi_get(dict_obj, *attrs, default=None):
    result = dict_obj
    for attr in attrs:
        if attr not in result:
            return default
        result = result[attr]
    return result
```

To use it, just call it like:

```py
x = multi_get(data, 'a', 'b', 'c', default=False)
```

Comment: Maybe change the if to the following one. Then the function can be used to iterate through json-like data structures that include lists as well:


    if (attr in result) or (isinstance(result, list) and isinstance(attr, int) and (attr < len(result))):


It checks if the current iteration of result is a list and the attribute an int and whether the list has enough elements. If yes the element can be accessed using the squre brackets syntax as well.

Answer (score 1):

There's two solutions:

#### Return a default value with defaultdict

You can use a [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), and intstantiate an inner level with another `defaultdict`. Then, if the key is missing, it'll return an empty dict without throwing errors:

```
from collections import defaultdict

>>> d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dict))
>>> d['a']['b']
{}
```

If you need more levels, you just have to chain many `lambda`.

Partial reference: [Multiple levels of 'collection.defaultdict' in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600790/multiple-levels-of-collection-defaultdict-in-python)

#### Handle the missing key with a try/except

Another way is to surronding the dict access with `try`/`except` block and manage the missing key through the `KeyError` exception (stop the program, return a default value, etc.)

```
try:
    x = data[a][b][c]
    # same code of your if statement
except KeyError:
    # stuff you do in your else
```