# nested list to nested dict python3

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested

I have a list as below:

```
L = [[0,[1,1.0]],
     [0,[2,0.5]],
     [1,[3,3.0]],
     [2,[1,0.33],
     [2,[4,1.5]]]
```

I would like to convert it into a nested dict as below:

```
D = {0:{1: 1.0,
        2: 0.5},
     1:{3: 3.0},
     2:{1: 0.33,
        4: 1.5}
     }
```

I'm not sure how to convert it. Any suggestion? Thank you!

Comment: I tried this https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict

Comment: I asked a similar question a while ago and got some good answers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45019709/how-to-process-dicts-within-nested-lists-in-an-ordered-manner-with-python

Comment: If it's given that the input and output are depth-2, the question and answers are not very general.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With [**`collections.defaultdict([default_factory[, ...]])`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) class:

```
import collections

L = [[0,[1,1.0]],
     [0,[2,0.5]],
     [1,[3,3.0]],
     [2,[1,0.33]],
     [2,[4,1.5]]]

d = collections.defaultdict(dict)
for k, (sub_k, v) in L:
    d[k][sub_k] = v

print(dict(d))
```

The output:

```
{0: {1: 1.0, 2: 0.5}, 1: {3: 3.0}, 2: {1: 0.33, 4: 1.5}}
```

---

- **`collections.defaultdict(dict)`** - the first argument provides the initial value for the `default_factory` attribute; it defaults to `None`. 
  Setting the `default_factory` to `dict` makes the `defaultdict` useful for building a *dictionary of dictionaries*.

Comment: use `for k, (k2, v) in L: `

Comment: my mistake I see now @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, let's do it

Answer (score 7):

Beginners friendly,

```
D = {}
for i, _list in L:
    if i not in D:
        D[i] = {_list[0] : _list[1]}
    else:
        D[i][_list[0]] = _list[1]})
```

Result:

```
{0: {1: 1.0, 2: 0.5}, 1: {3: 3.0}, 2: {1: 0.33, 4: 1.5}}
```

Comment: This isn't bad, but instead of `D[i].update({_list[0] : _list[1]})` use `D[i][_list[0]] = _list[1]`. and better yet, use `for k, (k2, v) in L: ... `D[k][k2] = v`

Comment: Yeah sure. Correct. @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: Use `.upate`  to update the dict with *another dynamic dict* with many possible entries. You want to update a single key-value pair, don't creat an unecessary intermediate `dict` to pass to the `update` method.

Comment: Yeah makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
L = [[0,[1,1.0]],
 [0,[2,0.5]],
 [1,[3,3.0]],
 [2,[1,0.33]],
 [2,[4,1.5]]
 ]

new_l = {a:dict([i[-1] for i in b]) for a, b in itertools.groupby(L, key=lambda x:x[0])}
```

Output:

```
{0: {1: 1.0, 2: 0.5}, 1: {3: 3.0}, 2: {1: 0.33, 4: 1.5}}
```

Comment: @MLam the other answer to this is better