# python - how to count number of numbers from columns?

Tags: python

I have a file with the following input data:

```
       IN   OUT
data1  2.3  1.3
data2  0.1  2.1
data3  1.5  2.8
dataX  ...  ...
```

There are thousands of such files and each has the same data1, data2, data3, ..., dataX
I'd like to count number of each value for each data and column from all files. Example:

In file 'data1-IN' (filename)

```
2.3 - 50    (times)
0.1 - 233   (times)
... - ...   (times)
```

In file 'data1-OUT' (filename)

```
2.1 - 1024 (times)
2.8 - 120  (times)
... - ...  (times)
```

In file 'data2-IN' (filename)

```
0.4 - 312    (times)
0.3 - 202   (times)
... - ...   (times)
```

In file 'data2-OUT' (filename)

```
1.1 - 124 (times)
3.8 - 451  (times)
... - ...  (times)
```

In file 'data3-IN' ...

Which Python data structure would be the best to count such data ? I wanted to use multidimensional dictionary but I am struggling with KeyErrors etc.

Answer (score 3):

You really want to use [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#counter-objects), perhaps contained in a [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
import collections
import csv

counts = collections.defaultdict(collections.Counter)

for filename in files:
    for line in csv.reader(open(filename, 'rb')):
         counts[filename + '-IN' ][line[1]] += 1
         counts[filename + '-OUT'][line[2]] += 1
```

Comment: Python 2.6.4 (r264:75706, Apr  2 2012, 20:24:27) [C] on sunos5
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more     information.
    >>> import collections
    >>> counts = collections.defaultdict(collections.Counter)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Counter'

Comment: From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079790/python-how-to-update-value-of-key-value-pair-in-nested-dictionary?lq=1 : dictionary = collections.defaultdict(lambda: collections.defaultdict(int))
 What is a difference between these two definitions ?

Comment: And this http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html says that defaultdict is available since 2.5

Comment: @przemol: A `Counter` offers more functionality than a `defaultdict` with an `int` value, such as retrieving the top counts, and combining multiple counters in various ways. Read the linked documentation for more details.

Comment: which version of python should I have to be able to use collections.Counter ?

Comment: `collections.Counter` was added in Python 2.7. The backported version on ActiveState I linked to in these comments runs on 2.5 and 2.6 as well.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently started using the [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) data frame. It has a CSV reader and makes slicing and dicing data very simple.