# How to change behavior of dict() for an instance

Tags: python, dictionary, overriding, autovivification

So I'm writing a class that extends a dictionary which right now uses a method "dictify" to transform itself into a dict. What I would like to do instead though is change it so that calling dict() on the object results in the same behavior, but I don't know which method to override. Is this not possible, or I am I missing something totally obvious? (And yes, I know the code below doesn't work but I hope it illustrates what I'm trying to do.)

```
from collections import defaultdict

class RecursiveDict(defaultdict):
    '''
    A recursive default dict.

    >>> a = RecursiveDict()
    >>> a[1][2][3] = 4
    >>> a.dictify()
    {1: {2: {3: 4}}}
    '''
    def __init__(self):
        super(RecursiveDict, self).__init__(RecursiveDict)

    def dictify(self):
        '''Get a standard dictionary of the items in the tree.'''
        return dict([(k, (v.dictify() if isinstance(v, dict) else v))
                     for (k, v) in self.items()])

    def __dict__(self):
        '''Get a standard dictionary of the items in the tree.'''
        print [(k, v) for (k, v) in self.items()]
        return dict([(k, (dict(v) if isinstance(v, dict) else v))
                     for (k, v) in self.items()])
```

EDIT: To show the problem more clearly:

```
>>> b = RecursiveDict()
>>> b[1][2][3] = 4
>>> b
defaultdict(<class '__main__.RecursiveDict'>, {1: defaultdict(<class '__main__.RecursiveDict'>, {2: defaultdict(<class '__main__.RecursiveDict'>, {3: 4})})})
>>> dict(b)
{1: defaultdict(<class '__main__.RecursiveDict'>, {2: defaultdict(<class '__main__.RecursiveDict'>, {3: 4})})}
>>> b.dictify()
{1: {2: {3: 4}}}
```

I want dict(b) to be same as b.dictify()

Comment: Some of the answers to this question suggest overriding `__iter__`, so that it returns key-value pairs in the same manner as `dict.iteritems`.  That might be a solution that suits your needs, but it will mean that your class no longer correctly implements the same interface as `dict` itself, since `dict.__iter__` is the same method as `dict.iterkeys`.  keep this in mind.

Comment: Are you trying to change the repr or to remove the automatic initialisation on a missing key? If you want the latter: The repr in the accepted answer is misleading, the inner dictionary is NOT a normal dictionary.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Nothing wrong with your approach, but this is similar to the Autovivification feature of Perl, which has been implemented in Python [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651794/whats-the-best-way-to-initialize-a-dict-of-dicts-in-python). Props to @nosklo for this.

```
class RecursiveDict(dict):
    """Implementation of perl's autovivification feature."""
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        try:
            return dict.__getitem__(self, item)
        except KeyError:
            value = self[item] = type(self)()
            return value

>>> a = RecursiveDict()
>>> a[1][2][3] = 4
>>> dict(a)
{1: {2: {3: 4}}}
```

**EDIT**

As suggested by @Rosh Oxymoron, using `__missing__` results in a more concise implementation. Requires Python >= 2.5

```
class RecursiveDict(dict):
    """Implementation of perl's autovivification feature."""
    def __missing__(self, key):
        value = self[key] = type(self)()
        return value
```

Comment: So that works when RecursiveDict inherits from dict which is awesome, although the line ">>> a[1][2][3] = 4" doesn't, but not when the parent class is a defaultdict.

Comment: Correct. This implementation does not use defaultdict. Is that critical? If so, I misunderstood your question

Comment: The problem with this is that dict(a) is still RecursiveDict, not dict.

Comment: Actually, this is a much better implementation that achieves the effect I was hoping to emulate. I was locked in the wrong mindset.

Comment: @Evgeny. I'm not sure that's true. type(dict(a)) yields <type 'dict'> on 2.7

Comment: Yeah, agreeing with Ceasar here.  Inheriting from dict directly removes the need for a dictify/dict() in the first place.

Comment: You could shorten this to the code of your except clause if you simply define `__missing__(self, item)`.

Comment: @Rob Cowie Oh, I see. I'm in 2.6 and didn't know about difference. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**edit**: As ironchefpython pointed out in comments, this isn't actually doing what I thought it did, as in my example `b[1]` is still a `RecursiveDict`.  This may still be useful, as you essentially get an object pretty similar Rob Cowie's answer, but it is built on `defaultdict`.

---

You can get the behavior you want (or something very similar) by overriding `__repr__`, check this out:

```
class RecursiveDict(defaultdict):
    def __init__(self):
        super(RecursiveDict, self).__init__(RecursiveDict)

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(dict(self))

>>> a = RecursiveDict()
>>> a[1][2][3] = 4
>>> a             # a looks like a normal dict since repr is overridden
{1: {2: {3: 4}}}
>>> type(a)
<class '__main__.RecursiveDict'>
>>> b = dict(a)
>>> b             # dict(a) gives us a normal dictionary
{1: {2: {3: 4}}}
>>> b[5][6] = 7   # obviously this won't work anymore
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 5
>>> type(b)
<type 'dict'>
```

There may be a better way to get to a normal dictionary view of the `defaultdict` than `dict(self)` but I couldn't find one, comment if you know how.

Comment: `__repr__` has absolutely nothing to do with `dict`.  You are merely changing how a `RecursiveDict` displays, and in your example, `type(b[1])` returns `<class '__main__.RecursiveDict'>`

Comment: @ironchefpython - Good catch, I edited my answer to reflect that.  Rob Cowie's answer has the same issue, when `dict()` is called on a nested structure using either of our answers, the inner dictionaries will still be `RecursiveDict`s.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want just to *print* it like a dict ? use this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

class RecursiveDict(defaultdict):
    '''
    A recursive default dict.

    >>> a = RecursiveDict()
    >>> a[1][2][3] = 4
    >>> a.dictify()
    {1: {2: {3: 4}}}
    >>> dict(a)
    {1: {2: {3: 4}}}

    '''
    def __init__(self):
        super(RecursiveDict, self).__init__(RecursiveDict)

    def dictify(self):
        '''Get a standard dictionary of the items in the tree.'''
        return dict([(k, (v.dictify() if isinstance(v, dict) else v))
                     for (k, v) in self.items()])

    def __dict__(self):
        '''Get a standard dictionary of the items in the tree.'''
        print [(k, v) for (k, v) in self.items()]
        return dict([(k, (dict(v) if isinstance(v, dict) else v))
                     for (k, v) in self.items()])

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.dictify())
```

Maybe you are looking for [`__missing__`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict) :

```
class RecursiveDict(dict):
    '''
    A recursive default dict.

    >>> a = RecursiveDict()
    >>> a[1][2][3] = 4
    >>> a
    {1: {2: {3: 4}}}
    >>> dict(a)
    {1: {2: {3: 4}}}

    '''

    def __missing__(self, key):
        self[key] = self.__class__()
        return self[key]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it.

I deleted my previous answer, because I found after looking at the source code, that if you call `dict(d)` on a `d` that is a subclass of `dict`, it makes a fast copy of the underlying hash in C, and returns a new dict object.

Sorry.

If you really want this behavior, you'll need to create a `RecursiveDict` class that doesn't inherit from `dict`, and implement the `__iter__` interface.

Answer (score 1):

You need to override `__iter__`.

```
def __iter__(self): 
    return iter((k, (v.dictify() if isinstance(v, dict) else v)) 
                for (k, v) in self.items())
```

Instead of `self.items()`, you should use `self.iteritems()` on Python 2.

Edit: OK, This seems to be your problem:

```
>>> class B(dict): __iter__ = lambda self: iter(((1, 2), (3, 4)))
... 
>>> b = B()
>>> dict(b)
{}
>>> class B(list): __iter__ = lambda self: iter(((1, 2), (3, 4)))
... 
>>> b = B()
>>> dict(b)
{1: 2, 3: 4}
```

So this method doesn't work if the object you're calling `dict()` on is a subclass of dict.

Edit 2: To be clear, `defaultdict` is a subclass of `dict`. dict(a_defaultdict) is still a no-op.

Comment: So this still doesn't work exactly right:

>>> a = RecursiveDict()

>>> a[1][2][3] = 4

>>> for b in a:
 print b

 
(1, {2: {3: 4}})

>>> dict(a)

{1: defaultdict(<class '__main__.RecursiveDict'>, {2: defaultdict(<class '__main__.RecursiveDict'>, {3: 4})})}

Comment: It turns out this just won't work if your class is subclassing `dict` because `dict(already_a_dict)` doesn't do anything.

Comment: Er, I'm subclassing defaultdict, so it's a little different.

Comment: No, it's not. `dict()` will still do nothing because `defaultdict` is a subclass of `dict`.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your dictify function working just do

```
dict = dictify
```

Update:
Here is a short way to have this recursive dict:

```
>>> def RecursiveDict():
...   return defaultdict(RecursiveDict)
```

Then you can:

```
d[1][2][3] = 5
d[1][2][4] = 6
>>> d
defaultdict(<function ReturnsRecursiveDict at 0x7f3ba453a5f0>, {1: defaultdict(<function ReturnsRecursiveDict at 0x7f3ba453a5f0>, {2: defaultdict(<function ReturnsRecursiveDict at 0x7f3ba453a5f0>, {3: 5, 4: 6})})})
```

I don't see a neat way to implement dictify.

Comment: You really don't want to do this, as you'll overwrite access to the built-in dict object.

Comment: And `dictify` is also an instance method as it's written now.

Comment: Nope I don't. But I don't think there is any other way to change how built-in dunction dict works, is there?