# Why does this queryset filter crash silently?

Tags: django, django-models

Basically, what i'm trying to do is filter out a company inside of a query, and this code is the result of a lot of debugging. we've reduced it to as simple as possible and can't work out why "for company in Company.objects.filter(pk="E0433CAE-1756-11E1-A97B-7071BC08AB6F"):" fails. anywhere else and it works perfectly :s

Autovivification, is nesting dictionaries automatically. See [Best way to automatically nest dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651794/whats-the-best-way-to-initialize-a-dict-of-dicts-in-python)

Code to be run:

```
def run_code(code, query_dict):
    code = code.replace('\r\n', '\n')
    import jmsdirectory.advert.models
    import jmsdirectory.boughtin.models
    import jmsdirectory.contacts.models
    import jmsdirectory.generic.models
    import jmsdirectory.joinerysoft.models
    import jmsdirectory.scheduler.models
    import jmsdirectory.suppliers.models
    # g = {'__builtins__': False }
    # try:
    print "WOOPS"
    # print g
    print query_dict
    class AutoVivification(dict):
        print "AutoVivification: 1"
        """Implementation of perl's autovivification feature."""
        def __getitem__(self, item):
            try:
                return dict.__getitem__(self, item)
            except KeyError:
                value = self[item] = type(self)()
                return value
    print "AutoVivification: 69"
    models = AutoVivification()
    print "AutoVivification: 71"

    for company in Company.objects.filter(pk="E0433CAE-1756-11E1-A97B-7071BC08AB6F"):
        print "AutoVivification: 74"
        for address in Address.objects.filter(company=query_dict['company']).exclude(allow_download=0):
            print "AutoVivification: 76"
            for contact in Contact.objects.filter(address=address.uuid).exclude(allow_download=0):
                print "AutoVivification: 78"
                for supplier in Supplier.objects.filter(company=query_dict['company']):
                    print "AutoVivification: 80"
                    for supplies in Supplies.objects.filter(supplier=supplier.uuid):
                        print "AutoVivification: 82"
                        models[company][address][contact][supplier] = supplies
                        print "AutoVivification: 84"
                        print models
    print "Rage!"
    result = models
    # exec code in locals()
    print "MEH!"
    # except:
        # print "Error in query set"
        # print traceback.print_exc()
        # return False
    return result
```

output:

```
Django version 1.2.7, using settings 'jmsdirectory.settings'
Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8002/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[21/May/2012 12:22:18] "POST /transfer/server/ HTTP/1.0" 200 162
[21/May/2012 12:22:18] "POST /transfer/server/ HTTP/1.0" 200 531
[21/May/2012 12:22:18] "POST /transfer/server/ HTTP/1.0" 200 162
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
WOOPS
{'company': u'E0433CAE-1756-11E1-A97B-7071BC08AB6F', 'contact': u'E047B1A8-1756-11E1-A97B-7071BC08AB6F', 'address': u'E0452488-1756-11E1-A97B-7071BC08AB6F'}
AutoVivification: 1
AutoVivification: 69
AutoVivification: 71
[21/May/2012 12:22:18] "POST /transfer/server/ HTTP/1.0" 200 129
```

model for company:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    uuid = UUIDField(primary_key=True)
    name =  models.CharField(null=True, blank=True,max_length=255,verbose_name=_('Company Name'))
    internal_name = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True,max_length=255,verbose_name=_('Internal Name'))
    reference = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True,max_length=255,verbose_name=_('Reference'))
    company_status = models.ForeignKey(CompanyStatus, null=True, db_column='company_status_uuid',verbose_name=(_('Company Status')), serialize=False)
    vat_number = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True,max_length=255,verbose_name=(_('Vat Number')))
    registration_number = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True,max_length=255,verbose_name=(_('Company Number')))
    discount = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    notes = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True,max_length=255)
    jms_code = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True,max_length=255)
    logo = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True,max_length=255)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, auto_now_add=True,verbose_name=_('Date Time'), serialize=False)
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, auto_now=True,verbose_name=_('Date Time Updated'), serialize=False)
    hidden = models.NullBooleanField(null=True, blank=True,default=0, serialize=False)
    user = UserField(null=True, blank=True, serialize=False)
    allow_download = models.NullBooleanField()
    is_modified = ModifiedField(serialize=False)
    companyid = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, serialize=False)
    seqno = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, serialize=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def advertiser_uuid(self):
        uuid = self.uuid
        today = date.today()

        from jmsdirectory.advert.models import Advertiser
        a=Advertiser.objects.filter(company=self,start_date__lte=today,end_date__gte=today)
        if len(a) > 0:
            return a[0].uuid
        else:
            return ''

    def advertiser(self):
        if self.advertiser_uuid() != '':
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def get_sequence (self) :

        if self.seqno is None :
            from django.db.models import Max
            max = Company.objects.all().aggregate(Max('seqno'))['seqno__max']
            if max is None :
                   self.companyid = 1
            else : self.companyid = max + 1
            self.seqno = 1
        else :
            self.seqno += 1

        self.save()
        return self.companyid, self.seqno

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = ('Companies')
        ordering = ('name',)
        db_table = 'company'
```

Fixed:

```
def run_code(code, query_dict):
    code = code.replace('\r\n', '\n')

    class AutoVivification(dict):
        """Implementation of perl's autovivification feature."""
        def __getitem__(self, item):
            try:
                return dict.__getitem__(self, item)
            except KeyError:
                value = self[item] = type(self)()
                return value

    models = AutoVivification()


    companies = Company.objects.filter(pk="E0433CAE-1756-11E1-A97B-7071BC08AB6F")
    addresses = Address.objects.filter(company=query_dict['company']).exclude(allow_download=0)
    suppliers = Supplier.objects.filter(company=query_dict['company'])
    for company in companies:
        for address in addresses:
            for contact in Contact.objects.filter(address=address.uuid).exclude(allow_download=0):
                for supplier in suppliers:
                    for supply in Supplies.objects.filter(supplier=supplier.uuid):
                        models[company][address][contact][supplier] = supply
    result = models

    return result
```

Comment: Can you reduce the example further and still reproduce the problem?

Comment: Are you sure that a Company with that PK exists?

Comment: Also note that when you do get this working, it's going to be **extremely** inefficient.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)?

Comment: Also, post your model for `Company`

Comment: defaultdict doesn't allow me to create nested dictionaries as easily

Comment: The company exists for that PK, i made sure, hence being hardwired

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is - it is not crashing, it is simply not returning anything so you are iterating over empty sets, hence nothing gets printed.

The long answer:

I'll try to help you out a bit, but my first suggestion would be to reduce your problem to its basics. For example, use [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) instead of your autovivi class.

You also have some other issues that I can see, for example:

`for address in Address.objects.filter(company=query_dict['company'])`

You are trying to filter on a PK against a string, I think you mean:

`for address in Address.objects.filter(company__uuid=query_dict['company'])`

as judging by your other models, I suspect your initial query should be:

`for company in Company.objects.filter(uuid="E0433CAE-1756-11E1-A97B-7071BC08AB6F")`

Similarly, you should fix your other queries:

`contact in Contact.objects.filter(address__uuid=address.uuid)` OR even better
`contact in Contact.objects.filter(address=address)` if you have the appropriate FK relationships.

However, even if you get this going, as Daniel hinted, this is highly inefficient. You should take advantage of [filter chaining](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#chaining-filters) and [foreign key lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#related-objects).

Comment: Oh, but it is crashing, either way it'd print at least something. even if i didn't expect it to print it, every single line had print statements surrounding it, so i can trace execution path in console. Another thing, this is/was already using many foreign keys lookups. i have hardwired in the uuid in attempt to narrow down where the fault is.

Comment: If it would have crashed, you have gotten an exception; the reason its not printing anything in your loops is because you are iterating over an empty set. It is equivalent to `for i in []: print i` this won't print anything, but its perfectly valid Python.

Comment: then why isn't it printing the line after the for loop? `print "Rage!"`

Comment: pk is also short for primary key, so should work correctly, as it does everywhere else :)