# No side-effect nested dictionary implementation

Tags: python, dictionary

There are at least two decent implementations of nested dictionary I've come across on SO, one is [to use defaultdict](https://stackoverflow.com/a/652226/548240), and the other is [to subclass dict](https://stackoverflow.com/a/652284/548240).

Both methods work fine for most functionalities, except that they both have a side-effect when accessing a non-existent key-value pair: it creates an **empty dictionary** for that key, stores that and returns it.

Ideally, I would like an implementation which would return `None` without creating an entry (e.g. an empty dictionary) upon an attempted access to a non-existent key. Is this feasible?

p.s. I am aware that we can avoid nested dictionary by using tuples as keys, but this implementation does not work me as I need to access the collection of entries at each level of the nested dictionary.

Comment: Would the `get` method suit your need? d.get(key, None) for dictionary `d`?

Comment: Which version(s) of Python need to be supported?

Comment: How would you like to create the nested entries?

Comment: @JanneKarila, `mydict[key][sub_key] = value`

Comment: @skyork That's the same as `d=mydict[key]; d[sub_key]=value`. By your definition, `d` would be `None`.

Comment: @BirdJaguarIV, that could be a workaround, but I'd still like to see a more proper solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must give up your requirement of returning None if you wish `d[key][subkey] = value` to work with missing keys. If `d[key] is None`, `d[key][subkey] = value` is equivalent to `None[subkey] = value`, which cannot work.

What you can do with missing values is to return an empty dict-like object without assigning it to a key just yet. If that object holds a reference to the parent, the assignment can be delayed until there is an explicit assignment down the hierachy.

An example implementation (this is incomplete, you must do more than override setitem to have a fully functional dict subclass):

```
class NestedDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, parentkey=None):
        self.parent = parent
        self.parentkey = parentkey

    def __missing__(self, key):
        return NestedDict(self, key)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if self.parent is not None:
            self.parent[self.parentkey] = self
            self.parent = None
        super(NestedDict, self).__setitem__(key, value)

>>> d = NestedDict()
>>> d[1][2][3] = 4
>>> d[2]
{}
>>> d.keys()
[1]
>>> d[1][2][3] 
4
```

---

An alternative approach would be to override `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` to do a nested lookup when the key is a tuple. This version gives a KeyError from `__getitem__` for missing keys in order to be consistent with regular dict. You can change it easily to return None instead if you wish.

```
class NestedDict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if isinstance(key, tuple):
            try:
                x = self
                for k in key:
                    x = x[k]
                return x
            except (KeyError, TypeError):
                raise KeyError(key)
        else:
            return super(NestedDict, self).__getitem__(key)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if isinstance(key, tuple):
            d = self
            for k in key[:-1]:
                d = d.setdefault(k, NestedDict())
            d[key[-1]] = value
        else:
            super(NestedDict, self).__setitem__(key, value)

>>> d = NestedDict()
>>> d[1,2,3] = 4
>>> d[1,2,3]
4
>>> d[1,2,4]
KeyError: (1, 2, 4)
>>> d
{1: {2: {3: 4}}}
```

Answer (score 2):

The *only* thing the two implementations you point to do over normal `dict`s is to return a `dict` when accessing a non-existing key. You want to revert that again, thus leaving you again with the default `dict` type:

```
>>> example = {}
>>> example['foo']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'foo'
>>> example['foo'] = {}
>>> example['foo']['bar'] = 1
```

If you want to return None instead of a dict, then just use `defaultdict(lambda: None)` instead:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> example = defaultdict(lambda: None)
>>> example['foo'] is None
True
```

Note that you cannot have it both ways; Python first must find the first key and resolve that to a `dict` before it can look up the second key:

```
>>> example['foo']['bar']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is unsubscriptable
```

Answer (score 1):

Python support [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) for such situations:

```
>>> d={}
>>> d[1]='Some'
>>> try:
...    att=d[1]
... except KeyError:
...    att=None
... 
>>> print att
Some
>>> try:
...    att=d[1][2][3]
... except KeyError:
...    att=None
... 
>>> print att
None
```

Roll that into a class or a function and it should easily support what I think you are looking for.