# multidimensional array automatic sub array initialization feature name?

Tags: php, python, language-agnostic, programming-languages

In some languages, like php, you don't need to manually initialize each dimension of a multidimensional array. You just specify the key path, and the language will automatically initialize the sub arrays if needed.

For example, in php I can just do

```
$foo = array();
$foo['sub1']['sub2']['sub3'] = 5;
```

Instead of having to manually initialize each level of sub array

```
$foo = array();
$foo['sub1'] = array();
$foo['sub1']['sub2'] = array();
$foo['sub1']['sub2']['sub3'] = 5;
```

<s>I know that python offers this convenience as well</s> I've seen python code that appears equivalent, so I figure there's a name for this feature.

**What is the name of this feature?**

Comment: Are you by any chance talking about dictionaries in Python? http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: A duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/651794/whats-the-best-way-to-initialize-a-dict-of-dicts-in-python

Comment: This isn't particularly language agnostic, when the meaning of the word "array" varies considerably between languages.

Comment: In Perl it's called autovivification.

Comment: Autovivification is an answer! someone post it.

Comment: Done. (11 more characters to go ...)

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the question is wrong: Python _doesn't_ offer this convenience; if you want it, you can build it yourself in a few lines of code, but it's not directly built-in, which means there's no standard name for it. Perl, on the other hand, does have a name for it (as Mark Dickinson says), and that's as close to a language-agnostic name as you're likely to find.

Comment: @abarnert:  Good point;  I've updated my answer.

Comment: @abarnet, thanks. I had seen it a few times in python code, and assumed it was native.

Comment: @rambocoder: The fact that it's not native, and not even built into the standard library, is actually intentional. Guido believes it just confuses people about how dicts work, and anyone who can't figure out how to implement it by using defaultdict recursively shouldn't be using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the corresponding feature in Perl is called [autovivification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autovivification).  As the wikipedia page points out, Python dictionaries don't have this feature by default, but it's easy to build something that behaves this way by making use of [collections.defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects).  See this recent [blog post](http://blogs.fluidinfo.com/terry/2012/05/26/autovivification-in-python-nested-defaultdicts-with-a-specific-final-type/) for some ideas.