# Python One-Line Tree using defaultdict. How to reduce the number of arguments required?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, defaultdict, autovivification

I'm using this [gist's](https://gist.github.com/hrldcpr/2012250) defaultdict one-line tree.

```
def tree(): return defaultdict(tree)
```

Currently, you must provide a separate `[]` for every node you want to add.

ie:

```
users = tree()
users['harold']['username']['hrldcpr']
users['handler']['username']['matthandlersux']
```

---

My question is, how would I be able to flatten the input so that I could provide a list to achieve the same result?

ie:

```
users = tree()
users['harold', 'username', 'hrldcpr']
users['handler', 'username', 'matthandlersux']
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Given that tree is a dict, may try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15077973/how-can-i-access-a-deeply-nested-dictionary-using-tuples

Comment: That is definitely the functionality I want, I will have a look into this one. Thanks!

Comment: You could create a class and implement your own `__getitem__` and `__setitem__`, but that is beyond the scope of a sensible SO question.

Comment: Yeah, the example that @fredtantini linked to does provide an example for that method. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply define a funcion, say `insert` to create the node by providing a `list` and `tree` as argument.

```
def insert(tree, List):
    for node in List:
        tree = tree[node]

users = tree()
insert(users, ['harold', 'username', 'hrldcpr'])
```

would create a structure as `{'harold' : {'username' : {'hrldcp' : {} } } }`