# python generating nested dictionary key error

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to create a nested dictionary from a mysql query but I am getting a key error

```
result = {}

for i, q in enumerate(query):

    result['data'][i]['firstName'] = q.first_name
    result['data'][i]['lastName'] = q.last_name
    result['data'][i]['email'] = q.email
```

error

```
KeyError: 'data'
```

desired result

```
result = {
    'data': {
        0: {'firstName': ''...}
        1: {'firstName': ''...}
        2: {'firstName': ''...}
    }
}
```

Comment: you want the keys to be the integers from 0 to `len(result)`?  why not use a list?

Comment: Why do you use `'data'` if you don't want to have it in `result`?

Comment: You should look up dictionaries in the docs

Comment: @KEYSER Be easy with OP, this is a typical assumption error for any beginner to assume flat dict assignment would create nested dict. If everyone needs to learn from docs (which we didnt refer), then why SOF ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best way to initialize a dict of dicts in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/651794/whats-the-best-way-to-initialize-a-dict-of-dicts-in-python)

Answer (score 10):

You wanted to create a nested dictionary

`result = {}` will create an assignment for a flat dictionary, whose items can have any values  like "string", "int", "list" or "dict"

For this flat assignment

python knows what to do for `result["first"]`

If you want "first" also to be another dictionary you need to tell Python by an assingment
`result['first'] = {}`.

otherwise, Python raises `"KeyError"`

I think you are looking for this :)

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> mydict = lambda: defaultdict(mydict)
>>> result = mydict()
>>> result['Python']['rules']['the world'] = "Yes I Agree"
>>> result['Python']['rules']['the world']
'Yes I Agree'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
result = {}
result['data'] = {}

for i, q in enumerate(query):
    result['data']['i'] = {}
    result['data'][i]['firstName'] = q.first_name
    result['data'][i]['lastName'] = q.last_name
    result['data'][i]['email'] = q.email
```

Alternatively, you can use you own class which adds the extra dicts automatically

```
class AutoDict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, k):
        self[k] = AutoDict()
        return self[k]

result = AutoDict()

for i, q in enumerate(query):
    result['data'][i]['firstName'] = q.first_name
    result['data'][i]['lastName'] = q.last_name
    result['data'][i]['email'] = q.email
```

Answer (score 0):

`result['data']` does exist. So you cannot add data to it.

Try this out at the start:

```
result = {'data': []};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the key `data` first:

```
result = {}
result['data'] = {}

for i, q in enumerate(query):
    result['data'][i] = {}
    result['data'][i]['firstName'] = q.first_name
    result['data'][i]['lastName'] = q.last_name
    result['data'][i]['email'] = q.email
```

Comment: I think that `result['data']['i'] = {}` should be `result['data'][i] = {}`