# KeyError Json in Python fix

Tags: python, json, discord.py, keyerror

```py
with open("data/tickets.json", "r") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

data[str(ticket.id)]["author"] = ctx.author.id

with open("data/tickets.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
```

I want to create in a json file, the ticket id and the author of this ticket.
But i want it looks so:

```json
{
    "random_channel_id" {
        "author": "random_user_id"
    }
}
```

But its give me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\omalo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 383, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\omalo\OneDrive\Desktop\Home Bot\cogs\Ticket.py", line 46, in TicketCreation
    data[str(ticket.id)]["author"] = ctx.author.id
KeyError: '995020823683412029'
```

Comment: Can you please provide sample of tickets.json file?

Comment: `data[str(ticket.id)]["author"] = ctx.author.id` would work if you have an existing `str(ticket.id)` and you want to add (or change) "author" in it. The error tells you it doesn't exist in this case. But, is this always the case? Are you trying to update an existing entry?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python generating nested dictionary key error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20410044/python-generating-nested-dictionary-key-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my testing and knowledge, the issue is that you are trying to create the `author` key in a nested dictionary that does not exist, which is not possible.

```py
>>> x = {}
>>> x[123]['author'] = 456
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 123
```

So if you create the key `123` first (or in your case, the ticket id), but with an empty dictionary, and then the `author` key in the nested dictionary, it will work:

```py
data[str(ticket.id)] = {}
data[str(ticket.id)]["author"] = ctx.author.id
```

Alternatively; you could also do it at once:

```py
data[str(ticket.id)] = {"author" : ctx.author.id}
```

Comment: Great answer but it assumes that OP wants to create a new `data` item as opposed to updating an existing one. I think we will need some clarification from OP.

Comment: I think that's what OP meant with "I want to create in a json file, the ticket id and the author of this ticket.", but you might be right. Guess we'll wait on OP and see.