# Updating nested dictionaries when data has existing key

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, nested

I am trying to update values in a nested dictionary, without over-writting previous entries when the key already exists.
For example, I have a dictionary:

```
  myDict = {}
  myDict["myKey"] = { "nestedDictKey1" : aValue }
```

giving,

```
 print myDict
>> { "myKey" : { "nestedDictKey1" : aValue }}
```

Now, I want to add another entry , under `"myKey"`

```
myDict["myKey"] = { "nestedDictKey2" : anotherValue }}
```

This will return:

```
print myDict
>> { "myKey" : { "nestedDictKey2" : anotherValue }}
```

But I want:

```
print myDict
>> { "myKey" : { "nestedDictKey1" : aValue , 
                 "nestedDictKey2" : anotherValue }}
```

Is there a way to update or append `"myKey"` with new values, without overwriting the previous ones?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is a very nice [general solution to dealing with nested dicts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/652226/4258430):

```
import collections
def makehash():
    return collections.defaultdict(makehash)
```

That allows nested keys to be set at any level:

```
myDict = makehash()
myDict["myKey"]["nestedDictKey1"] = aValue
myDict["myKey"]["nestedDictKey2"] = anotherValue
myDict["myKey"]["nestedDictKey3"]["furtherNestedDictKey"] = aThirdValue
```

For a single level of nesting, `defaultdict` can be used directly:

```
from collections import defaultdict
myDict = defaultdict(dict)
myDict["myKey"]["nestedDictKey1"] = aValue
myDict["myKey"]["nestedDictKey2"] = anotherValue
```

And here's a way using only `dict`:

```
try:
  myDict["myKey"]["nestedDictKey2"] = anotherValue
except KeyError:
  myDict["myKey"] = {"nestedDictKey2": anotherValue}
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use `collections.defaultdict` for this, and just set the key-value pairs within the nested dictionary.

```
from collections import defaultdict
my_dict = defaultdict(dict)
my_dict['myKey']['nestedDictKey1'] = a_value
my_dict['myKey']['nestedDictKey2'] = another_value
```

Alternatively, you can also write those last 2 lines as

```
my_dict['myKey'].update({"nestedDictKey1" : a_value })
my_dict['myKey'].update({"nestedDictKey2" : another_value })
```

Answer (score 2):

You could treat the nested dict as immutable:

`myDict["myKey"] = dict(myDict["myKey"], **{ "nestedDictKey2" : anotherValue })`

Comment: I think this is the most neat solution

Answer (score 2):

You can write a generator to update key in nested dictionary, like this.

```
def update_key(key, value, dictionary):
        for k, v in dictionary.items():
            if k == key:
                dictionary[key]=value
            elif isinstance(v, dict):
                for result in update_key(key, value, v):
                    yield result
            elif isinstance(v, list):
                for d in v:
                    if isinstance(d, dict):
                        for result in update_key(key, value, d):
                            yield result

list(update_key('Any level key', 'Any value', DICTIONARY))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from ndicts.ndicts import NestedDict

nd = NestedDict()
nd["myKey", "nestedDictKey1"] = 0
nd["myKey", "nestedDictKey2"] = 1
```

```
>>> nd
NestedDict({'myKey': {'nestedDictKey1': 0, 'nestedDictKey2': 1}})
>>> nd.to_dict()
{'myKey': {'nestedDictKey1': 0, 'nestedDictKey2': 1}}
```

To install [ndicts](https://github.com/edd313/ndicts) `pip install ndicts`

Answer (score 0):

```
myDict["myKey"]["nestedDictKey2"] = anotherValue
```

`myDict["myKey"]` returns the nested dictionary to which we can add another key like we do for any dictionary :)

Example:

```
>>> d = {'myKey' : {'k1' : 'v1'}}
>>> d['myKey']['k2'] = 'v2'
>>> d
{'myKey': {'k2': 'v2', 'k1': 'v1'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote myself a function to tackle this issue

```
def updateDict2keys(myDict,mykey1,mykey2,myitems):
"""
updates a dictionary by appending values at given keys (generating key2 if not already existing)
input: dictionary, key1, key2 and items to append
output: dictionary orgnanized as {mykey1:{mykey2:myitems}}
"""
    myDict.setdefault(mykey1, {})[mykey2] = myitems
    return myDict
```