# Updating dictionary without overwriting existing key-value pair?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have an input file as below, from which I can construct my dictionary

General format

```
<IP_1>
KEY_1=VALUE_1
KEY_2=VALUE_2

<IP_2>
KEY_1=VALUE_1
KEY_2=VALUE_2
```

Example

```
192.168.1.1
USER_NAME=admin
PASSWORD=admin123

192.168.1.2
USER_NAME=user
PASSWORD=user123
```

Expected dictionary should look like this:

```
>>print dictionary_of_ip
{'192.168.1.1':{'USER_NAME'='admin','PASSWORD'='admin123'},
 '192.168.1.2':{'USER_NAME'='user','PASSWORD'='user123'}}
```

Essentially a dictionary within dictionary

Below is my code:

```
def generate_key_value_pair(filePath, sep='='):
    dict_of_ip = {}
    slave_properties = {}
    with open(filePath, "rt") as f:
        for line in f:
            stripped_line = line.strip()
            if stripped_line and stripped_line[0].isdigit():
                #print 'Found Ip'
                ip = stripped_line
                dict_of_ip[ip] = ''
            elif stripped_line and stripped_line[0].isupper():
                #print "Found attributes")
                key_value = stripped_line.split(sep)
                key = key_value[0].strip()
                value = key_value[1].strip()
                slave_properties[key] = value
                dict_of_ip[ip] = slave_properties

    return dict_of_ip
```

I am able to get the first of IP and their attributes as expected, but the second set of values from second IP are overwriting the first one.

```
>>print dict_of_ip
{'192.168.1.1': {'USER_NAME': 'user', 'PASSWORD': 'user123'},
 '192.168.1.2': {'USER_NAME': 'user', 'PASSWORD': 'user123'}}
```

`dict_of_ip[ip] = slave_properties`  is causing the overwrite. How do I prevent the values from the `'192.168.1.2'` key overwriting the first one?

Comment: `if ip not in dict_of_ip: dict_of_ip[ip] = slave_properties` should do it...

Comment: wouldn't a multidict be easier?

Comment: Hint: How many different dictionaries does the variable `slave_properties` refer to over its lifetime?

Comment: so you say: if key already exists then don't update it, only create. See my comment, just test for key already in dict...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating nested dictionaries when data has existing key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27118687/updating-nested-dictionaries-when-data-has-existing-key)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre , i tried with your suggestion   , but i received the output as {'192.168.1.1': '', '192.168.1.2': ''}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def generate_key_value_pair(filePath, sep='='):
    dict_of_ip = {}
    with open(filePath, "rt") as f:
        for line in f:
            stripped_line = line.strip()
            if stripped_line and stripped_line[0].isdigit():
                #print 'Found Ip'
                slave_properties = {}
                ip = stripped_line
                dict_of_ip[ip] = ''
            elif stripped_line and stripped_line[0].isupper():
                #print "Found attributes")
                key_value = stripped_line.split(sep)
                key = key_value[0].strip()
                value = key_value[1].strip()
                slave_properties[key] = value
                dict_of_ip[ip] = slave_properties

    return dict_of_ip
```

You where using the same (modified) `dict`. I didn't change your code logic on purpose, just changed the `slave_properties = {}` to where it should be

You can even remove your `slave_properties` and use the `dict` alone

```
def generate_key_value_pair(filePath, sep='='):
    dict_of_ip = {}
    with open(filePath, "rt") as f:
        for line in f:
            stripped_line = line.strip()
            if stripped_line and stripped_line[0].isdigit():
                #print 'Found Ip'
                ip = stripped_line
                dict_of_ip[ip] = {}
            elif stripped_line and stripped_line[0].isupper():
                #print "Found attributes")
                key_value = stripped_line.split(sep)
                key = key_value[0].strip()
                value = key_value[1].strip()
                dict_of_ip[ip][key] = value

    return dict_of_ip
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not do `slave_properties = {}` in the loop, so you are referring to the same dict object when you think you are you are creating a new dict with

```
slave_properties[key] = value
dict_of_ip[ip] = slave_properties
```

Answer (score 0):

This becomes easier and more efficient if you use a Python's High-Performance datatypes. For instance, here's the same code with the [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) instead of creating your own collection type.

```
from collections import defaultdict

dict_of_ip = defaultdict(dict)   # This creates a dictionary of dictionaries for you.

ip = None  
for line in f:
    stripped_line = line.strip() 
    if stripped_line and stripped_line[0].isdigit():
        ip = stripped_line  # The value for the ip only changes if a new 
                            # IP is detected. Otherwise the algorithm proceeds
                            # with the older IP address to the nested dict. 

    elif stripped_line and stripped_line[0].isupper():
        key_value = stripped_line.split(sep)  
        key = key_value[0].strip()
        value = key_value[1].strip()
        dict_of_ip[ip][key] = value # IP set in the earlier if-loop.
```

More specifically though, the reason you were getting the error was you were editting the same `slave_properties` dictionary for each subdictionary. So changes in one propagate to another.

Answer (score 0):

You could choose a regex way in combination with a dict comprehension:

```
import re

string = """
192.168.1.1
USER_NAME=admin
PASSWORD=admin123

192.168.1.2
USER_NAME=user
PASSWORD=user123
"""

regex = re.compile(r"""
    ^
    (?P<ip>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)[\n\r]
    USER_NAME=(?P<user>.+)[\r\n]
    PASSWORD=(?P<password>.+)
    """, re.MULTILINE | re.VERBOSE)

users = {match.group('ip'):
            {'USER_NAME': match.group('user'), 
            'PASSWORD': match.group('password')}
            for match in regex.finditer(string)}

print(users)
# {'192.168.1.2': {'USER_NAME': 'user', 'PASSWORD': 'user123'}, '192.168.1.1': {'USER_NAME': 'admin', 'PASSWORD': 'admin123'}}
```

See it [**working on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/JzCF5w). Here's the corresponding [**demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/84JF9h/1).

Answer (score 0):

Just move the initialization of `slave_properties` to right after an IP address is recognized. That way it will start out empty for each one encountered (I also removed the unnecessary initialization you had there of `dict_of_ip[ip]`).

```
from pprint import pprint

def generate_key_value_pair(filePath, sep='='):
    dict_of_ip = {}

    with open(filePath, "rt") as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            if line and line[0].isdigit():  # ip?
                slave_properties = {}  # initialize
                ip = line
            elif line and line[0].isupper():
                key_value = line.split(sep)
                key = key_value[0].strip()
                value = key_value[1].strip()
                slave_properties[key] = value
                dict_of_ip[ip] = slave_properties

    return dict_of_ip

result = generate_key_value_pair('ips.txt')
pprint(result)
```

Output:

```
{'192.168.1.1': {'PASSWORD': 'admin123', 'USER_NAME': 'admin'},
 '192.168.1.2': {'PASSWORD': 'user123', 'USER_NAME': 'user'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

A compact solution using slices and a dictcomp:

```
with open("data.txt", "r") as f:
    f = [i.strip() for i in f.readlines()]
    ipdict = {ip: {'USER_NAME': user[10:], 'PASSWORD': password[9:]} 
              for ip, user, password in zip(f[0::4], f[1::4], f[2::4])}
```