# Cannot update nested dictionary properly

Tags: python, dictionary

I am working with Python 3.8.5

I have created some objects like this:

```py
class TestClass:
    def __init__(self, key, value):
        self.key=key
        self.value=value

test1 = TestClass(1, 'a')
test2 = TestClass(2, 'b')
test3 = TestClass(3, 'c')

test_list = [test1, test2, test3]
```

I want to create a dictionary to keep track the modifications in this objects:

```py
object_mapper = {
    'ClassNotRelevant': None,
    'TestClass': None,
    'ClassNotRelevant2': None,
}

test_dict = {test.key: object_mapper for test in test_list}

#output
{1: {'ClassNotRelevant': None, 'TestClass': None, 'ClassNotRelevant2': None},
 2: {'ClassNotRelevant': None, 'TestClass': None, 'ClassNotRelevant2': None},
 3: {'ClassNotRelevant': None, 'TestClass': None, 'ClassNotRelevant2': None}}
```

Now, I want to set the value property for each class in the dictionary, like this:

```py
#expected dictionary
#output
{1: {'ClassNotRelevant': None, 'TestClass': 'a', 'ClassNotRelevant2': None},
 2: {'ClassNotRelevant': None, 'TestClass':'b', 'ClassNotRelevant2': None},
 3: {'ClassNotRelevant': None, 'TestClass':'c', 'ClassNotRelevant2': None}}
```

I am trying to do the following:

```py
for test in test_list:
    test_dict[test.key]['TestClass']= test.value
```

but the output is:

```py
{1: {'ClassNotRelevant': None, 'TestClass': 'c', 'ClassNotRelevant2': None},
 2: {'ClassNotRelevant': None, 'TestClass': 'c', 'ClassNotRelevant2': None},
 3: {'ClassNotRelevant': None, 'TestClass': 'c', 'ClassNotRelevant2': None}}
```

I have tried the different solutions found in:  [Updating nested dictionaries when data has existing key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27118687/updating-nested-dictionaries-when-data-has-existing-key/27118776)

But anything worked, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You've only created one `object_mapper` dict that you use for all entries in `test_dict`.  You need each entry to have its own copy of the dict.  So do `test_dict = {test.key: object_mapper.copy() for test in test_list}`.  This will perform a shallow copy of `object_mapper` for each entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies here

When you do this

`test_dict = {test.key: object_mapper for test in test_list}`

Output is

```
{1: {'ClassNotRelevant': None, 'TestClass': None, 'ClassNotRelevant2': None},
 2: {'ClassNotRelevant': None, 'TestClass': None, 'ClassNotRelevant2': None},
 3: {'ClassNotRelevant': None, 'TestClass': None, 'ClassNotRelevant2': None}}
```

This `{'ClassNotRelevant': None, 'TestClass': None, 'ClassNotRelevant2': None}` is the same object (`object_mapper`) corresponding to key `1 2 3'

So when you update using this :

```
for test in test_list:
    test_dict[test.key]['TestClass']= test.value
```

This updates the `object_mapper` object so,

After 1st iteration:

```
{1: {'ClassNotRelevant': None, 'TestClass': 'a', 'ClassNotRelevant2': None},
 2: {'ClassNotRelevant': None, 'TestClass': 'a', 'ClassNotRelevant2': None},
 3: {'ClassNotRelevant': None, 'TestClass': 'a', 'ClassNotRelevant2': None}}
```

2nd Iteration

```
{1: {'ClassNotRelevant': None, 'TestClass': 'b', 'ClassNotRelevant2': None},
 2: {'ClassNotRelevant': None, 'TestClass': 'b', 'ClassNotRelevant2': None},
 3: {'ClassNotRelevant': None, 'TestClass': 'b', 'ClassNotRelevant2': None}}
```

3rd Iteration

```
{1: {'ClassNotRelevant': None, 'TestClass': 'c', 'ClassNotRelevant2': None},
 2: {'ClassNotRelevant': None, 'TestClass': 'c', 'ClassNotRelevant2': None},
 3: {'ClassNotRelevant': None, 'TestClass': 'c', 'ClassNotRelevant2': None}}
```

So Instead of

`test_dict = {test.key: object_mapper for test in test_list}`

use

`test_dict = {test.key: object_mapper.copy() for test in test_list}`

which will create `shallow_copy` of `object_mapper` object for each entry, instead of putting `object_mapper` object itself there.

Comment: A little TL;DR but ultimately the right advice.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code which will solve the question. It will create a copy of the `object_mapper` for each iteration.

```
test_dict = {test.key: object_mapper.copy() for test in test_list}
for test in test_list:
    test_dict[test.key]['TestClass']=test.value
print(test_dict)
```