# How to construct multi-level classes using dictionaries

Tags: python, oop

I need a construction like:

```
mainclass["identificator 1"].categories["identificator 2"].plots["another string"].x_values
```

I write this with many classes like:

```
class c_mainclass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.categories={}
        self.categories["identificator 2"]=c_categories()

class c_categories(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.plots={}
        self.plots["another string"]=c_plots()

class c_plots(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.x_values=[2,3,45,6]
        self.y_values=[5,7,8,4]

mainclass={}

mainclass["identificator 1"]=c_mainclass()
#mainclass["identificator bla"]=c_mainclass(bla etc)

print(mainclass["identificator 1"].categories["identificator 2"].plots["another string"].x_values)
```

I'd like to define that all as "subattributes" within only one class like:

```
class c_mainclass={}:

    setattr(mainclass["identificator 1"],"categories",{})
    ...etc.
```

What's the most practical way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something akin to [Autovivification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autovivification) check [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651794/whats-the-best-way-to-initialize-a-dict-of-dicts-in-python) out.

(this is pasted from the answer to the linked SO question.)

```
class AutoVivification(dict):
    """Implementation of perl's autovivification feature."""
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        try:
            return dict.__getitem__(self, item)
        except KeyError:
            value = self[item] = type(self)()
            return value

a = AutoVivification()

a[1][2][3] = 4
a[1][3][3] = 5
a[1][2]['test'] = 6

print a

{1: {2: {'test': 6, 3: 4}, 3: {3: 5}}}
```