# Python: 'Deep create' keys in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

Being a Perl convert I'm wondering, if it is possible in Python to create more then one level of keys in a dictionary.

In Perl, if I have an empty hash, I can e.g. write this:

```
my %h;  # emtpy hash
$h{level1}{level2}{level3} = "something";
```

Do I really have to do the same thing in Python like this:

```
h = {}   # empty dictionary
h['level1'] = {}
h['level1']['level2'] = {}
h['level1']['level2']['level3'] = "something"
```

or is there a shortcut?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651794/whats-the-best-way-to-initialize-a-dict-of-dicts-in-python

Comment: Thanks. This shows a lot of solutions. Sorry, but I just didn't find it; should have used 'autovivification' as a keyword...

Comment: No problem, sometimes the right search keys can be the real question!